# Iterator.each: why is this working

Tags: ruby, syntax, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I was refactoring a bit of code in a project for work when I came across an odd bit of syntax.  I confirmed it has been in the file since it was first created and the bit of code is being called.

```
worksheet.each 1 do |row|
  Dashboard::LocalizedMessagingField.create({blah blah blah})
end
```

When I run something like the following in irb it complains about 1 for 0 parameters on each.

```
[1,2,3].each 1 do |i|
  puts i
end
```

Why does it work in the RoR application?  Anyone ever see something like this before?

Comment: Can you please answer this question with the answer you provide in your edit and then accept it?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: @solipsicle: You shouldn't need any reputation to edit your own question, or to post an answer (to anyone's question).

Comment: You should be able to *now*, solipsicle. There's a short waiting period, but that's over now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after a bit of digging. We have the Spreadsheet gem installed and it provides an *each* method that takes a parameter to skip the first n rows of a spreadsheet.

```
def each skip=dimensions[0], &block
  skip.upto(dimensions[1] - 1) do |idx|
    block.call row(idx)
  end
end
```